# Cloud SQL: Python Client API defaults to utf8mb3 character set on CSV file import

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, load-data-infile, mysql-loadfile

I am using Google Cloud's import API to load CSV file in Google Cloud Storage to a Cloud SQL MySQL 5.7 database:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/import

The import API generates a LOAD DATA INFILE command to MySQL database that assumes 'utf8' character set. However, the data in my CSV files uses 'utf8mb4' encoding which is a superset of 'utf8'. This causes the load process to fail when some strings cannot be encoded to 'utf8':

```
Exception: CloudSQL Exception: {'kind': 'sql#operation', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/***', 'targetProject': '***', 'targetId': '***', 'targetLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/***', 'name': '0211c99e-0633-42f1-9ee1-069473308273', 'operationType': 'IMPORT', 'status': 'RUNNING', 'user': '***', 'insertTime': '2019-01-14T02:36:39.861Z', 'startTime': '2019-01-14T02:36:39.972Z', 'error': {'kind': 'sql#operationErrors', 'errors': [{'kind': 'sql#operationError', 'code': 'ERROR_RDBMS', 'message': "Import CSV error: Error 1300: Invalid utf8 character string: ''Afikanisitani|'Apekanikana|A Phu Han (Afghanistan)|A Phú Hãn '\n"}]}, 'importContext': {'kind': 'sql#importContext', 'uri': '***', 'database': '**', 'importUser': '', 'csvImportOptions': {'table': '***'}}}
```

Relevant piece: **"'message': "Import CSV error: Error 1300: Invalid utf8 character string:"**

Is there a way to add 'utf8mb4' CHARACTER SET using the import API (or any other character set for that matter)?

I tried experimenting with adding 'character set': 'utf8mb4' in 'csvImportOptions' dictionary, but it appears import API only expects 'table' and 'columns' keys in that dict.

Note that if I directly run the LOAD DATA INFILE command from MySQL client, I am able to import the CSV with no issues:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myCSVFile.csv'
INTO TABLE 'my table'
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

```
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4', credentials=credentials)

# Project ID of the project that contains the instance.
project = 'my-project'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# Cloud SQL instance ID. This does not include the project ID.
instance = 'my-instance'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

instances_import_request_body = {
    "importContext": {
        "kind": "sql#importContext",
        "fileType": "CSV",
        "uri": gcs_uri,
        "database": database,
        "csvImportOptions": {
            "table": table
        }
    }
}

request = service.instances().import_(project=project, instance=instance, body=instances_import_request_body)
response = request.execute()
```

**ADDITIONAL DATA POINT**
It is clear to me that the LOAD DATA INFILE query that Google's API is generating is defaulting to 'utf8' character set.

Fails with the same error message as the API

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'problematic.csv'
INTO TABLE my_table
**CHARACTER SET utf8**
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\"'

ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8 character string: ''Afikanisitani|'Apekanikana|A Phu Han (Afghanistan)|A Phú Hãn '
```

Works:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'problematic.csv'
INTO TABLE my_table
**CHARACTER SET utf8mb4**
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\"'

Query OK, 75641 rows affected (1.14 sec)
Records: 75641  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The documentation here is incorrect: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing

```
  LOAD DATA INFILE ... ***CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'***
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the following flag on your Google Cloud SQL instance:

```
character-set-server: utf8mb4
```

[Configuring Database Flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags)

CLI Command:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --database-flags character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

The database flags are listed under the `settings` as the collection `databaseFlags`:

```
gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

**Warning: Any flag not included in the `patch` command will be set back to its default value.**

Comment: I executed this command, except the flag uses underscores e.g. character_set_server=utf8mb4. I verified the variable was set on the instance: 
`mysql> show variables like 'character_set_server';
| character_set_server | utf8mb4 |`

Unfortunately, still the same error: "Import failed: Import CSV error: Error 1300: Invalid utf8 character string: ''Afikanisitani|'Apekanikana|A Phu Han (Afghanistan)|A Phú Hãn '"

Comment: @OsvaldoBanuelos - Did you create a new table?

Comment: Yes, new database, new table. Also restarted the Cloud SQL instance. I keep investigating this issue, and it's clear that the API is defaulting to a LOAD DATA INFILE command with 'utf8'. See the edit in original post.

Comment: Use the `gcloud` command line to diplay the flags. I showed an example in my answer.

Comment: databaseFlags:
  - name: character_set_server
    value: utf8mb4

Comment: I am looking for all flags. Is there something else overwriding or defaulting to `utf8`?

Comment: I don't have any other flags defined. I did this: gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE] | less, /utf8, and the only match is the flag we defined. Here's the output around it:
dataDiskType: PD_SSD
  databaseFlags:
  - name: character_set_server
    value: utf8mb4
  ipConfiguration:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186677/discussion-between-osvaldo-banuelos-and-john-hanley).